# How to convert a RDD into another Java list of POJO?

Tags: java, apache-spark

The input is a `RDD` and desired output is Java list of `POJO`

Giving analogous example from SQL:

```sql
select col1, col2, col3, sum(col4) from table
group by col1, col2, col3;
```

Being totally new to Java Spark, has been able to reach so far for tuple2 :

```java
JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<Integer, String>, Integer> pairRDD = 
    rdd.mapToPair(e -> new Tuple2<>(new Tuple2<>(e.getCol1(), e.getCol2()), e.getCol3()))
       .reduceByKey((v1, v2) -> v1 + v2);
```

How do I use this `PairRDD` to create a Java list of `POJO`, having attributes of the key and summed value ?